# Defining a vector of struct and passing it as pointer in C - error: initialization from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, pointers

I want to define a vector of struct. This vector should have the elements : user and role.

```
struct UserToRole_S
{
    char user[SERVAL_HTTP_MAX_LEN_USER_NAME + 1];
    unsigned int  role;
};

typedef struct UserToRole_S UserToRole

#define ENDROLE 5

static UserToRole user_role[6] =
{
    {"user5", ADMIN},
    {"user4", GUEST},
    {"user3", GUEST},
    {"user2", GUEST},
    {"user1", ADMIN},
    {"andreea", ENDROLE},
};

UserToRole const *usertoroleTable[2] =
{
        &user_role,
        NULL
};

extern UserToRole const *usertoroleTable[];
```

But then I get the error: initialization from incompatible pointer type

What is wrong with my code? Definition of the vector?

Comment: Note: `typedef struct UserToRole_S UserToRole` <<=== add semi-colon.

Comment: .. and `&user_role,` <<=== remove ampersand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `typedef`, you can't use the bare name of a structure as a type name in C.

Either add:

```
typedef struct UserToRole_S UserToRole_S;
```

or use:

```
static struct UserToRole_S user_role[] =
```

and so on, i.e. replace the bare name with the full `struct UserToRole_S` type name.